# How to configure Electron, Webpack, Babel, React, and JSX?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, reactjs, electron

I'm getting started with Electron and I'm trying to set up my app to use React. I'm also new to React, Webpack, Babel, NPM...pretty much the whole Node.js ecosystem and build tools. I started from scratch. I think I'm pretty close, but I'm stuck trying to compile my main JSX file:

```
$ webpack
Hash: fa3346c3ff9bfd21133d
Version: webpack 1.12.14
Time: 41ms
   [0] ./js/helloworld.jsx 0 bytes [built] [failed]

ERROR in ./js/helloworld.jsx
Module parse failed: /...path.../js/helloworld.jsx Line 5: Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
|   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
|   document.getElementById('example')
| );
```

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  //...

  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~>6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-photonkit": "~>0.4.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14"
  }
}
```

...my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

...my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/helloworld.jsx"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "out"),
    publicPath: 'out/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
};
```

...and the `helloworld.jsx` file:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get everything configured correctly?

Comment: Is your code open source? I've been attempting to use React and .jsx files with Electron as well and it has been rather difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `babel-loader` so webpack knows to use babel to process your files

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-loader
```

And then in your `webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/helloworld.jsx"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "out"),
    publicPath: 'out/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }
    ]
  }
};
```